# DateTime in PHP returns the wrong value?

Tags: php

First off, i have been struggling for two days non stop to figure out what I need to with this code and still stuck in the square one.

so here I am again and i hope someone shed a light on this issue as my head is exploding.

what I need to do is to get the difference between two values using DateTime in PHP.

The first value is 00:00 which is a set value and never gonna change.

the second value is $offset/3600 * 1 which is a time difference between two timezones.

the code I am using is this:

```
<?php
if (0 > $offset)
{
// set an object with the current date
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTime(00, 00);

// the second date
$date2 = new DateTime($offset/3600 * 1);

// apply the diff() method, getting a DateInterval object ($diDiff)
$diDiff = $date->diff($date2) ;
}
echo $diDiff->format("H:i");
?>
```

the code above echo's this:  `H:i`   and nothing else!

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The $offset comes from here:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //be sure to validate and clean your variables
    $timezone1 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone1']);
    $timezone2 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone2']);

    //then you can use them in a PHP function. 
    function get_timezone_offset( $origin_tz, $remote_tz ) {
    $timezone1 = new DateTimeZone( $origin_tz );
    $timezone2 = new DateTimeZone( $remote_tz );

    $datetime1 = new DateTime("now", $timezone1);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime("now", $timezone2);

    $offset = $timezone1->getOffset($datetime1) - $timezone2->getOffset($datetime2);
    return $offset;

}

$offset = get_timezone_offset($timezone1, $timezone2);

}

?>
```

timezone1 and timezone2 are two dropdown lists with php timezones inside them and they are identical.

like so:

```
  <select name="timezone2" id="timezone2" class="timezone2">
                        <?php
                    foreach($options as $key => $value)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'. $key .'" label="'. $value .'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
<option value="Africa/Abidjan" label="Abidjan">Abidjan</option>
<option value="Africa/Accra" label="Accra">Accra</option>
<option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa" label="Addis Ababa">Addis Ababa</option>
<option value="Africa/Algiers" label="Algiers">Algiers</option>
<option value="Africa/Asmara" label="Asmara">Asmara</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Where do you set $offset?

Comment: the $offset is set right at the top of the page and when the user chooses two locations/timezones.

Comment: Starting off, you have `if (0 > $offset)`, do you mean to check `if zero is greater than $offset`?

Comment: @Jason, Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

With the DateInterval object, you [have to prefix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) all the formatting letters with the "%" character.  So use:

```
echo $diDiff->format("%H:%i");
```

Happy hunting!

Comment: okay Brian, that worked in a way but the value that it returns is wrong! i.e. the time difference ($offset) between London and New York is -5 hours. so if London is 00:00, the New York should be 19:00 but the value that it is shown now with my code is 20:35. is that because of DST?

Comment: Well that may be because of how you're doing time zones.  Where does $offset come from?

Comment: In general, what I do is convert everything to Unix time, do whatever calculations I need, and output it as date() formatted for timezone.  But then at least all the calcs are universal to the server.